# Can't switch Apache port binding

Tags: apache

I have apache 2.2 http server installed on windows 7.  Port 80 is already being used and I am attempting to bind apache to an alternative free port.  I have amended the C:\Apache\ApacheHTTPserver\Apache24\conf\httpd.txt file to change the value of Listen 80 to Listen 88 or Listen 7777 (I have checked the ports 88 and 7777 are free) and also changed ServerName localhost:80 to ServerName localhost:88 or ServerName localhost:7777 respectively.  But when I attempt to start the Apache service I am given an error and it states this in the logs;

The Apache service named  reported the following error:
OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80

Why will this not change the Apache port number?

Comment: 1.) the config filename is httpd.conf and not httpd.txt 2.) check, that apache is start as admin to set lower port bindings

Comment: @donald123 Thanks for response.  Yes I have checked the name is httpd.conf.  The start apache as admin - I searched on google on how to do this and it seems this is not advisable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered what I was doing wrong.  I was editing the httpd.conf file by locating it in Windows Explorer and opening in notepad and saving.  But when I opened the httpd.conf file using Start >> Apache HTTP Server 2.2 >> Configure Apache Server and amend the port to 88 the service starts okay

Comment: When a non-admin user edits files in program files, modern Windows virtualizes the changes. You see it but the server process doesn't.

Comment: @covener Thanks for your feedback Covener